# GA debugger proclaiming to sending hit but no data in google analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager

We currently have GTM/analytics setup on an android app with data appearing successfully within google analytics. However we decided to send data to a new Google analytics property (which will be used for the live version), so just the GA tracking ID was changed within the GTM container, now no data is showing in the new property after more the 24 hours (the old account showed data within minutes via real time report)

GA debugger also confirms the screensview hit is being sent to the new GA ID, but no data showing which is strange as the only thing that was changed here was the GA ID itself (which does work for the old account).

Comment: Could you post the output of the GA debugger, with your GA tracking ID obscured?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, after removing all tags, triggers and variables and re adding them again and uploading the new json file it seem to have worked!

Maybe this was something to do with the recent GTM update om September 14, 2016